Summing up filtered html columns takes to much time, how to speed it up?
With my very basic "knowledge" in javascript I have written the following generic function to sum up filtered columns (i.e. the content of the visible <td> elements of a filtered column). The unfiltered table has about 2000 lines and 55 columns. The function has the following parameters:

tabID: is the ID of the table

colNum: selects the number of the column to be filtered and summed up

colS: is the ID of the column

rec: just indicates if the sum needs to be converted e.g. from kWh to GWh (than rec would be 1'000'000)


The function is executed as soon as selection via dropdown in the html-table is made (on change).
The problem is that it takes to much time (about 1-2 mins) until I get the result. Is there a solution (which I can understand) that performs quicker?
As the page itself as the table are created dynamically I can only provide screenshots. Hope that helps for better understanding?
screenshot 1, screenshot 2, screenshot 3
function htmlTableColSum(tabID, colNum, colS, rec) {
  var table = document.getElementById("" + tabID + "");
  var sumCol = 0;
  let count = $('#' + tabID + ' tbody tr').length;

  for (var i = 1; i < count - 1; i++) {
    if ($('#' + tabID + ' tbody tr:eq(' + i + ')').is(':visible')) {
      if (table.rows[i].cells[colNum].innerHTML !== "") {
        sumCol = sumCol + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[colNum].innerHTML);
      }
    }
  }
  
  sumCol = sumCol / rec;
  if (rec > 1) {
    sumCol = sumCol.toFixed(2)
  }
  
  document.getElementById("" + colS + "").innerHTML = "" + sumCol;
}


Can you please add the relevant HTML so we can create a working example of the context you're working in

Added three screenshots of the html. The page is created dynamically, therefore the screenshots. Thank you.

You could try the following. Same principal just some code performance changes
function htmlTableColSum(tabID, colNum, colS, rec) {
  var sumCol = 0;
  var visibleRows = $('#' + tabID + ' tbody tr:visible');
  var count = visibleRows.length;

  visibleRows.each(function(i, row) {
    var cellValue = row.cells[colNum].innerHTML;
    if (cellValue !== "") {
      sumCol += parseInt(cellValue);
    }
  });

  sumCol /= rec;
  if (rec > 1) {
    sumCol = sumCol.toFixed(2);
  }

  document.getElementById(colS).innerHTML = sumCol;
}

That being said there is no way for me to physically test this without some sort of mock data set to populate the DOM to do any tests.

Just perfect :-). Now it takes only a few seconds. Must be because of the for-loop... Thank you very much, you're just great!!

Not a problem glad I could help :) The major performance gain was using a .each rather than for and also filtering the visible rows first before. The way you had it you were going through each element and DOM context access can be expensive.. expensive === slow
